# f90 error in global climate model

Tags: runtime-error

I compiled my model code successfully, however it gives me this error when I try to run it:

forrtl: severe (408): fort: (8): Attempt to fetch from allocatable variable COS_ZENITH when it is not allocated.

I checked several questions and answers online but I'm not sure how I should handle this problem in my case. I think the error message seems quite clear but I don't have enough experience with fortran so I don't know if it's a bug or I have to modify the code etc.

This is the module of the code that apparently gives trouble:

```
MODULE mo_zenith
! 
! Description: 
!   <Say what this module is for> 
! 
! Current Code Owner: <Name of person responsible for this code> 
! 
! History: 
!  
! Version   Date     Comment 
! -------   ----     ------- 
! <version> <date>   Original code. <Your name> 
! 
! Code Description: 
!   Language:           Fortran 90. 
!   Software Standards: "European Standards for Writing and  
!     Documenting Exchangeable Fortran 90 Code". 
! 
! Modules used: 
! 
USE mo_mpi,          ONLY: p_parallel_io, p_bcast, p_io
USE mo_kind,         ONLY: dp
USE mo_io_units,     ONLY: nout
USE mo_exception,    ONLY: finish
USE mo_jsbach_grid , ONLY: domain_type

IMPLICIT NONE

PRIVATE

PUBLIC :: compute_orbit_and_solar, init_zenith, cos_zenith

REAL(dp), ALLOCATABLE, SAVE :: cos_zenith(:)    !< Cosine of solar       zenith angle for domain

LOGICAL :: module_configured  = .FALSE.
LOGICAL :: module_initialized = .FALSE.

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE compute_orbit_and_solar(domain)

! Compute orbital parameters for current time step

! Called from *jsbalone_driver* at the beginning of each time step
! If coupled with ECHAM: 
!    this is done in *pre_radiation* from *mo_radiation*, called in      *scan1*
!    the cosine of zenith angle is passed from ECHAM to the interface
!    the interface copies the packed zenith angle to *cos_zenith*

USE mo_time_control, ONLY: l_orbvsop87, get_orbit_times
USE mo_orbit,        ONLY: orbit_kepler, orbit_vsop87
USE mo_radiation_parameters,    ONLY: nmonth,solar_parameters

TYPE(domain_type), INTENT(in) :: domain

LOGICAL :: l_rad_call = .FALSE.
LOGICAL :: lyr_perp   = .FALSE.  !< Switch to specify perpetual vsop87  year
INTEGER :: yr_perp    = -99999   !< year if lyr_perp == .TRUE.

REAL(dp) :: rasc_sun, decl_sun, dist_sun, orbit_date, time_of_day
REAL(dp) :: flx_ratio, cos_mu0(domain%nland,1),  daylght_frc(domain%nland,1)
REAL(dp), DIMENSION(domain%nland,1) :: sinlon, sinlat, coslon, coslat
INTEGER :: nland

nland = domain%nland

IF (.NOT. module_initialized) CALL init_zenith(domain)

CALL get_orbit_times(l_rad_call, lyr_perp, nmonth, yr_perp,    time_of_day, orbit_date)

IF (l_orbvsop87) THEN
   CALL orbit_vsop87 (orbit_date, rasc_sun, decl_sun, dist_sun)
ELSE
   CALL orbit_kepler (orbit_date, rasc_sun, decl_sun, dist_sun)
END IF

sinlon(:,1) = domain%sinlon(1:nland)
sinlat(:,1) = domain%sinlat(1:nland)
coslon(:,1) = domain%coslon(1:nland)
coslat(:,1) = domain%coslat(1:nland)

CALL solar_parameters(decl_sun, dist_sun, time_of_day       &
                     ,sinlon, sinlat, coslon, coslat        &
                     ,flx_ratio, cos_mu0, daylght_frc)

cos_zenith(1:nland) = cos_mu0(1:nland,1)

END SUBROUTINE compute_orbit_and_solar
!
    !=================================================================================================
SUBROUTINE init_zenith(domain)

! Pre-compute some work quantities for domain

TYPE(domain_type), INTENT(in) :: domain

IF (module_initialized) RETURN

ALLOCATE(cos_zenith(domain%nland))

module_initialized = .TRUE.

END SUBROUTINE init_zenith

END MODULE mo_zenith
```

any idea?
Thank you in advance!